# Process image on non-ui thread

Tags: c#, wpf, image-processing

I currently have a **WriteableBitmap** that I want to process on a **non-UI thread**.

I basicly want to reuse the image that is the source of my Image-control and process it in a Task.Run.

```
WriteableBitmap bitmap;

Task.Run(() =>
{
     // Process the bitmap here
});
```

Unfortunately I receive the following exception because it is blocked on the UI-thread

> The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.

Note - I don't want to process the code on the UI thread!

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objects like WriteableBitmap must be used on the thread they were created. So you have to allocate it on the other thread.

If you would like to use the processed image back on UI after processing on the worker thread, you should do one of the following:

- Copy the result back to the UI (i.e. by copyPixels).
- Freeze the object (you have to call the Freeze() method on the worker thread). Then you cannot change the object anymore but you will be able to use it for read-only on whatever thread you want.

Answer (score -1):

`WriteableBitmap` is **DispatcherObject**, only the thread that the **Dispatcher** was created on may access the **DispatcherObject** directly. To access a **DispatcherObject** from a thread other than the thread the **DispatcherObject** was created on, we need to call Invoke or BeginInvoke on the Dispatcher the **DispatcherObject** is associated with. And the delegate will be executed on that thread, so the render thread will block.

If you want to work with raw pixel data, `WriteableBitmap` will be a good choice. We can use the **CopyPixels** method of the WriteableBitmap to **load** the pixels data to a int array, afher we modify the data in the `int array` we can use the **WritePixels** method to update the pixels of the `WriteableBitmap`. So, maybe you can try the operate the int array in the background thread.